# Formatting a column in Excel as % without multiplying with 100 along with rounding off the value

Tags: formatting, excel-2007, excel-2010, number-formatting

Is it possible to come up with a format which does following

1. Round off the value.
2. Show % symbol without multiplying the number with 100
3. If the value is negative show the number in red color with brackets along with % sign.

Ex: If the value is:

- -5.34 should be converted as (5%) in red color
- -4.78 should be converted as (5%) in red color
- 6.33  should be converted as 6 in regular color

Currently I am using `0.00##\%;[Red](0.00##\%)` format which shows % symbol wihtout multiplying value with 100 & show negative number in red color with brackets around the value but it *does NOT round off the values*.

Thank you

Comment: To Answer my own question: I am using following format :  ##0\%;[Red](##0\%)

Answer (score 2):

Following format is doing the trick for me : `##0\%;[Red](##0\%)`